# The result of a javascript action (a roulette) to open specific pages

Tags: javascript

I'm using the code for this roulette for a personal project. The roulette is all working fine but I'm trying to have **the result of the roulette**  open a specific page in the same window. I'm not sure how to target the result. If for example the result is N, I do not want the result to display on the page (as it currently does) but would like a page to open instead. I have tried adding a function at the end to try and make it work but can't figure it out

Below are the functions in the code:

```
var options = ["N", "NNE", "NE", "ENE", "E", "ESE", "SE", "SES", "S", "SSW", "SW", "WSW", "W", "WWW", "NW", "NWW"];
var startAngle = 0;
var arc = Math.PI / (options.length / 2);
var spinTimeout = null;
var spinArcStart = 10;
var spinTime = 0;
var spinTimeTotal = 0;
var ctx;

document.getElementById("spin").addEventListener("click", spin);
function byte2Hex(n) {
    var nybHexString = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    return String(nybHexString.substr((n >> 4) & 0x0F,1)) + nybHexString.substr(n & 0x0F,1);
}

function drawRouletteWheel() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        var outsideRadius = 200;
        var textRadius = 160;
        var insideRadius = 1;
}

function spin() {
    spinAngleStart = Math.random() * 10 + 10;
    spinTime = 0;
    spinTimeTotal = Math.random() * 3 + 4 * 1000;
    rotateWheel();
}

function rotateWheel() {
    spinTime += 30;
    if(spinTime >= spinTimeTotal) {
        stopRotateWheel();
        return;
    }

    var spinAngle = spinAngleStart - easeOut(spinTime, 0, spinAngleStart, spinTimeTotal);
    startAngle += (spinAngle * Math.PI / 180);
    drawRouletteWheel();
    spinTimeout = setTimeout('rotateWheel()', 30);
}

function stopRotateWheel() {
    clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
    var degrees = startAngle * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
    var arcd = arc * 180 / Math.PI;
    var index = Math.floor((360 - degrees % 360) / arcd);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.font = '30px Roboto Condensed, Arial';
    var text = options[index]
    ctx.fillText(text, 250 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 250 + 10);
    ctx.restore();
}

function easeOut(t, b, c, d) {
    var ts = (t/=d)*t;
    var tc = ts*t;
    return b+c*(tc + -3*ts + 3*t);
}

drawRouletteWheel();


Below is the approach I have taken to try and make this work:


function openDestinationResult() {
    var NNE = "index.html";
    var NE = "index.html";
    var ENE = "index.html";
    var E = "index.html";
    var ESE = "index.html";
    var SE = "index.html";
    var SES = "index.html";
    var S = "index.html";
    var SSW = "index.html";
    var SW = "index.html";
    var WSW = "index.html";
    var W = "index.html";
    var WWW = "index.html";
    var NW = "index.html";
    var N = "index.html";


if (NNE == "NNE");
{
   window.open(
 'page1.html'
 );
}  
    else if (NE === "NE")
    {
        window.open("page2.html");
    }
    else if (ENE === "ENE")
    {
        window.open("page3.html");
    }
    else if (E === "E")
    {
        window.open("page4.html");
    }

    else if (ESE === "ESE")
    {
        window.open("page5.html");
    }
    .....  
else      {
window.open("page5.html"); 
}
    }
```

I'm new at using javascript so bear with me!

Thanks for any tips/solutions.

cheers

Comment: Your `if` is written wrongly. I assume you need `==` instead of a single `=` and you need to remove the `;` after the `if` statement. See [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) for more info on `if` statements.

Comment: still not fixed, just correct the "if". Issue remains unsoved

Comment: let me understand you are setting the var `$100` to `"index.html"` then testing if it is equal to `"$100"`, same question for the var `$200`.

Comment: Could you put your new code somewhere to see, we are obviously missing some pieces (plus you could debug the code putting some debug message , like alert(var) )

Comment: I have copied above the code roulette code with the function I added at the end to try and get the result I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the current window redirect to a new url you can use:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.abc.com.au";
```

Comment: I want the result of the roulette to open a specific window automatically (instead of displaying it on the page)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Location.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)

```
document.location.replace("http://www.abc.com.au");
```

Comment: I've added it in my code above, let me know your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

```
function openDestinationResult() {
var $100 = "index.html";
var $200 = "content.html";
...
if ($100=="$100");
{
   window.open(
 'http://www.abc.com.au',
 '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.Whether a new tab or window is created, is decided by the browser (setting).
 );
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I've made a few edits using some of your suggestions. How it it looking now?